# Is wordexp in libc on OSX 10.9.5 known to leak?

Tags: c, macos, debugging, memory-leaks, libc

### Is [`wordexp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/wordexp.3.html) on **OSX 10.9.5** known to leak memory? And if not, what is wrong with my code?

On my own local machine running **OSX 10.10.5** I run my code through Valgrind and get **no lost bytes**.

**No leaks** on my **Ubuntu Linux** machine either.

However, when I turned on valgrind checks on my [travis-ci](http://www.travis-ci.org) account that uses **OSX 10.9.5** I suddenly get a leak from memory allocated inside of [`wordexp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/wordexp.3.html) even though I free it using [`wordfree`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/wordexp.3.html) as the man page describes:

```
==8968== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8968==    definitely lost: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==8968==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8968==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

**OSX 10.9.5** `uname` output:

```
Darwin 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

**OSX 10.9.5** `sw_vers` output:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.5
BuildVersion:   13F34
```

**OSX 10.9.5** libc version **1197.1.1** `otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib`:

```
/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

**OSX 10.10.5** libc version **1213.0.0**:

```
/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Relevant code (Please use the link to the full code below if compiling):
https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/wordexp_test

```c
static void xfree(void *p)
{
    void **pp;
    assert(p);

    pp = (void **)p;

    if (*pp)
    {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}

char **test_wordexp(const char *cmdline, int *argc)
{
    char **argv = NULL;
    size_t i;
    int ret;
    wordexp_t p;
    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));

    // Note! This expands shell variables.
    if ((ret = wordexp(cmdline, &p, 0)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "wordexp error %d: '%s'\n", ret, cmdline);
        return NULL;
    }

    *argc = p.we_wordc;

    if (!(argv = calloc(*argc, sizeof(char *))))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
        goto fail;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < p.we_wordc; i++)
    {
        if (!(argv[i] = strdup(p.we_wordv[i])))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory!\n");
            goto fail;
        }
    }

    wordfree(&p);

    return argv;

fail:
    wordfree(&p);

    if (argv)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < (size_t)*argc; i++)
        {
            xfree(&argv[i]);
        }

        free(argv);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Full code: https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/wordexp_test

Travis job with failed OSX but successful Linux:

https://travis-ci.org/JoakimSoderberg/wordexp_test/builds/83194932

Exact line of OSX Travis job with leak error:

https://travis-ci.org/JoakimSoderberg/wordexp_test/jobs/83194937#L78

The `wordexp` is [known](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9025572) on OSX for having used Perl in its implementation. But apparently doesn't any more.

- [Perl version](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.40.1/gen/FreeBSD/wordexp.c)
- [New verison](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1044.1.2/gen/FreeBSD/wordexp.c)

Also I did not manage to find the exact source code links that I know is found in the involved libc versions mentioned above.

Comment: should not `xfree(&argv[i]);` be `free(argv[i]);`?

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )  then fix the warnings.  On my ubuntu linux 14.04, there is no `xfree()` function.

Comment: after prefexing the posted code with: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE  (200809L)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wordexp.h>
#include <string.h>` so it would compile, the compiler still showed the following problems: `warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions (on the 'for' statement)`  and `warning: implicit declaration of function 'xfree`

Comment: I pasted a link to the full sources including the `xfree` function, so please use that. And ah yes I missed that `we_wordc` was a `size_t`. I broke this code out from a bigger project, which uses the `xfree` it could be simplified here, but I don't think that's the issue since it works fine on other platforms. The `unsigned` mismatch I also have a hard time being the cause of this issue. But thanks for the pointers I will update the question

Comment: Exact same issue with your fixes

Comment: @mch `xfree` is just short for `free(p); p = NULL;`, so `xfree(&argv[i]);` is the same as `free(argv[i]); argv[i] = NULL;`

Comment: could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120084/do-we-need-to-call-wordfree-upon-wordexp-failure ?